# Unable to pass string from each field into for loop

Tags: string, bash, for-loop, awk, grep

I'm new to Bash scripting, and been writing a script to check different log files if they exist or not, and I'm a bit stuck here.

```bash
clientlist=/path/to/logfile/which/consists/of/client/names 
# I grepped only the client name from the logfile,
# and piped into awk to add ".log" to each client name 
clients=$(grep -i 'list of client assets:' $clientlist | cut -d":" -f1 | awk '{print $NF".log"}')
echo "Clients : $clients"
#For example "Clients: Apple.log
#                      Samsung.log
#                      Nokia.log
#                      ...."

export alertfiles="*_$clients" #path/to/each/client/logfiles

for file in $alertfiles
do
    # I will test each ".log" file of each client, if it exists or not 
    test  -f "$file" && echo $file exists || { echo Error: $file  does not exist && exit; }
done
```

The code above greps the client name from the log file, and using `awk`, added `.log` at the end of each client field. From the output, I'm trying to pass `eachclientname.log` from each field into one variable, i.e. `alertfiles`, and construct a path to be tested for the file existence.

The number of clients is indefinite and may vary from time to time.

The code I have returns the client name as a whole:

```bash
"Clients: Apple.log
         Samsung.log
         Nokia.log
         ....."
```

I'm unsure of how to pass each client name one by one into the loop, so that each client name log file will be tested if it exists or not. How can I do this?

```bash
export alertfiles="*_$clients" #path/to/each/client/logfiles
```

I want to have `$clients` output listed here one by one, so that it returns all client name one by one, and not as a whole thing, and I can pass that into the loop, so the client log filename gets checked one by one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with sample contents of `/path/to/logfile/which/consists/of/client/names` and associated alertfiles (some present, some not). It's hard to imagine what format `$clientlist` might be in where `grep -i 'list of client assets:' $clientlist | cut -d":" -f1 | awk '{print $NF".log"}'` produces the desired output and even if it did, you don't need grep and cut when you're using awk.

Comment: `grep -i 'list of client assets:' $clientlist | cut -d":" -f1 | awk '{print $NF".log"}'` could be written as `awk 'tolower($0) ~ /list of client assets:/{sub(/:.*/,""); print $NF".log"}'` but that would imply that the client names come BEFORE `list of client assets:` on each line which seems unlikely and it'd fail if any file name contained `:`.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. `$clients` is already a list of tokens which you can loop over, though saving it in a variable seems like an unnecessary waste of memory.

Comment: Also, why are you looping over the wildcard and _then_ checking if the files exist? With `nullglob` you can make sure that `file` is not looped at all if there are no matches on the wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bash array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)s.

(BTW: I can't test this as you have not supplied an example of the input data)

```bash
clientlist=/path/to/logfile/which/consists/of/client/names
logfilebase=/path/to/where/the/logfiles/should/exist
declare -a clients=($(grep -i 'list of client assets:' $clientlist | cut -d":" -f1))

for item in "${clients[@]}"; do
  if [ -e ${logfilebase}/${item}.log ]; then
    echo "$item exists"
  else
    echo "$item does not exist - quit"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: You have a quoting error; you want `for item in "${clients[@]}"; do`

Comment: oops, you are correct.  I did not run it, just wrote from memory.

Comment: @Jay The shell check prefer mapfile or read -a to split command output (or quote to avoid splitting) here ```declare -a clients=($(grep -i 'list of client assets:' $clientlist | cut -d":" -f1))```

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment?  There are numerous ways to construct arrays in BASH. I just chose the simplest in the context of the question.  I refer you to the link in the answer for the documentation.  A quick Google search yields lots of results, e.g. This page https://gist.github.com/msuchodolski/531da1ee9c2338dc7424fe004db74374    There are numerous Q/A on this subect on SE too.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you are asking. `$clients` is already a list of tokens which you can loop over, though saving it in a variable seems like an unnecessary waste of memory.

Also, why are you looping over the wildcard and then checking if the files exist? With `nullglob` you can make sure that file is not looped at all if there are no matches on the wildcard.

I'm guessing your actual question is how to check whether the log files exist in the directory you nominated.

I have refactored your code to do the `grep` and `cut` in Awk, too. See [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

```
shopt -s nullglob   # bash feature

awk -F: 'tolower($0) ~ /list of client assets:/ {
  print(tolower($1).log))' "$clientlist" |
while read -r client; do
  # some heavy guessing here
  for file in path/to/each/"$client"/logfiles/*; do
     test -f "$file" && echo "$file" exists || { echo "Error: $file  does not exist" && exit; }
  done
done
```